# What do Teimanim do with regards to modern questions?

Tags: minhag, rambam, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, yemenite-temani

It's known that Teimanim follow the opinion of the Rambam exclusively.

What do they (or even more so Rambamists) do when there are questions not discussed at all by the Rambam? For example,

1. Do Teimanim use electricity on Shabbos?
2. What do they do regarding date-lines?
3. What do they do when they are in the far north where there is no sunset?

Do they follow other poskim in such cases? Do they have their own responsa where they try to deduce the Rambam's opinion?

Comment: You should check out Rav Yosef Kapach's works. That might be it.

Comment: I don't think it's true that Teimanim follow the opinion of the Rambam exclusively.

Comment: @Daniel not anymore that is. because they are uneducated for the most part.

Comment: It's actually "known" otherwise http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9878/yemenite-shofar-not-from-sheep

Comment: @DoubleAA they have their own masoroh on things. they differ than the rambam at over 60 places. however, everything else was 100% rambam up until shaamis came along and the moving to arasS yisroel.

Answer (score 3):

***(In order of your original question)***

First of all, I would like to correct an apparent misconception regarding the halakhic positions of traditional Temanim. While it is true that they they generally follow the Rambam as opposed to later authorities, at no time in their history did the Jews of Yemen follow the Mishneh Torah ***exclusively***. Instead, the previous *Mara De-Athra* of Yemen - i.e. before the time of the Rambam - was the Rasag (Rav Sa`adia Gaon) and even then they followed other Gaonic opinions in many areas of halakhah. While there were strains of "Rambamists" in Teman who attempted to exclusively follow the Rambam in all matters, the sentiment never truly caught on, even among the *Dar Daim* of early 20th Century.

(NOTE: When we speak of "traditional Temanim" in this regard, we are really talking about the *Baladhim* and not the later *Shami'im* who abandoned many of their ancestral traditions in favor of adopting Sefaradi practices based largely on the Qabbalah and the Shulhan Arukh of Rav Yosef Karo.)

Regarding the problems of modernity, the problem for the Mishneh Torah is not so different from the Shulhan Arukh. In actual fact, Rav Karo merely quotes the language of the Rambam in about 85% of his code. So, what is difficult for one is difficult for the other. However, from my experience, Temanim who still follow the Rambam attempt to derive - using logic and the Gemara - the shitah of the Rambam for more modern halakhic issues. Rav Ratzon Arusi shlit"a will often learn through the traditional sources, such as the Tur and the Shulhan Arukh, as well as modern *poseqim* like Rabbi Mosheh Feinshtein z"l in order to determine the correct halakhic position in his estimation.

In many instances, things which are "issues" for later codifiers of *halakhah* are simply non-issues in the halakhic formulation of the Rambam. So, they will simply disregard it and teach their communities that for the Rambam it was not an issue and that one is not required to worry about it.

1. While there are groups of traditional Temanim who ***do*** use electricity on *Yomim Tovim*, there are none who use electricity on *Shabboth*. Those who use electricity of *Shabboth* are not Temanim at all, but only "Rambamists" who generally take a simplistic and almost "Karaite-style" approach to the text of the Mishneh Torah. An approach which has led to a multitude or errors - some of which are rather severe - among non-Temani [would-be] devotees of the Rambam.
2. They handle the question in similar manner to other authorities. However, the premise(s) for determining any one position regarding date lines are taken from the Rambam as opposed to other authorities.
3. The answer to this question is essentially the same as above.

As for modern halakhic commentaries and responsa, you can find thousands of such questions and answers on the following websites (which are in Hebrew ONLY):

A. [www.net-sah.org](http://net-sah.org)

B. [www.moreshet.co.il](http://moreshet.co.il) - there are many *rabbanim* who contribute to this site, so click on the "Ask The Rav" tab, and then select "Rav Ratzon Arusi" to see his *pisqei teshuvah* according to the Rambam.

Comment: i heard mori arusi has become too leanient and less rambam-like recently. he wants to be more "politically correct" when it comes to certain halochoth. this is one reason to not always rely 100% on what he says. this notion of becoming lenient in halocho in order to fall into the category of not falling away from the way the klal does things between teimonim and the rest of the jewish world is hurting teimonim more than anybody else unfortunately.

Comment: What you have heard regarding Mori Arusi is NOT true. I have personally spoken with him in his office in the Mo'assah Datith of Kiryath Ono, Israel many times, have translated many of his teshuvoth into English, and have even work for a time for his Machon Mosheh. I can tell you that EVERYTHING that he does is based 100% on the Rambam. If not based on the Mishneh Torah, then based on an explicit teshuvah of the Rambam, or upon other Maimonidean literature. He receives much criticism from the non-Hebrew speaking "Rambamist" world for not taking their simplistic approach to Mishneh Torah.

Comment: But I can assure you that he does not depart from the Rambam's pesaq in Mishneh Torah for "political correctness" or other shallow motives. Please do not believe these types of inaccurate stories, and please refrain from spreading them. Kol tuv.

Comment: a friend of mine has been in contact with him many times as well, and he visited him recently here in nyc when he came in early july. he said that indeed teimonim did heeshta7awoyoh in yaman but since the klal doesnt do it anymore we shouldnt do it either. this is indeed wrong. maybe my friend misheard him or didnt understand him, but this is what he had said in regards to proper tafillo as stated in the RaMbaM. i havent talked to him so i dont know what he would say to my questinos, but my friend had issues with wat he answered to some of his questions pertaining to day to day life

Comment: also if you would like to join the mi yodea chat, look ontop of the site where it says chat and join wadibarto bom.

Comment: It is only "wrong" from the perspective of a simplistic, karaite-style understanding of the Rambam. While the Rambam certainly describes hishtahawayah as lying prostrate, and that it certainly should be done after each tafillah during nafilath apayim, he also says "lo le-shanoth mipanei mahloqeth." And the fact is that the Rambam gives a heter to be mishtahawah and recite nafilath apayim in a completely different location from where one says his tafillah. Thus, the halakhic advice that is usually given is to finish praying with the ssibbur and then do hishtahawayah in private.

Comment: However, to perform hishtahawayah in the middle of a ssibbur which does not practice such a custom - except during Yom HaKippurim - is wrong since it is almost sure to arouse a mahloqeth. To quote Mori Yusef z"l (as printed in Shu"T HaRiva"d - Sefer Mada) "...many of these things [relating to tafillah be-ssibbur] are de-rabbanan and they [i.e. the non-Rambam qehilloth] have valid opinions [from the Geonim, et al] on whom to rely, but to arouse a mahloqeth is an issur me-de-oraytha and for such a sin there NO ONE on whom to rely." Many non-Hebrew speaking, non-Yemenite "Rambamists" simply...

Comment: ...do what they understand from their limited reading of the Rambam no matter who they are with or how it will affect others. They wrongly justify it by invalidating anyone who is not like them. This is not the way of the Rambam - he did not live this way or teach halakhah this way. I do not mean to bring an argument from the greatness of a scholar (since even great scholars are wrong at times), but I challenge anyone who would criticize either Mori Arusi shlit"a or Mori Yusef z"l for their positions to first contend with the Rambam as understood by their mesorah. Kol tuv.

Comment: i hear waht you are saying and i am totally fine with it. i am a stern follower of many things Mori Gafe7 says in his peirush and some things i have yet to see eye to eye with him on until i learn more. but as for now, in regards to heeshta7awayoh, the rambam brings down how to pray and says it as halocho not minhagh. he gives a heter for a person to do it home if he doesnt feel comfortable doing it in shul or if there is no room or some other reason. BUT not for the reason that it is to cause a ma7loqath since everyone in his meenyan did it. there wouldnt be a ma7loqath in his shul

Comment: in regards to this topic. although there was a ma7loqath in his time in other shuls in his time about this topic. also i dont think mori gafe7 talks bout heeshta7awoyoh in that tashuvo but about different piyyutim like bar yo7ai and lacho dodi. in regards to mori ro9on arusi, i indeed have problems with him in this regard. he personally showed,in his have of 70, my friend how to teimonim did nafillath apayeem according to their masoro. i am not arguing on his masoro. i am arguing on him for not doing it. like i said earlier, he said his reason is so that we dont go against klal. and i disagree

Comment: But, nevertheless, he does not choose to do so out of "political correctness." Also, no one is claiming that the Rambam was saying "lo le-shanoth mipanei mahloqeth" with regard to this issue specifically. Rather, it is a general principle given which, while applying in many other areas, certainly applies in the context of tafillah be-ssibbur. The world has changed. It is not the same as when the Rambam wrote his work. The fact that we have qibbuss galuyoth ("a gathering of [various] Jewish traditions in one place [ i.e. Eress Yisrael] means that we must change the way in which we deal with...

Comment: also in regards to what ashkanazim do on yom cippur and rosh hashono, according to mori gafe7 is wrong as he brings down in his peirush on the halocho of heeshta7awoyoh in the rambam: http://oi40.tinypic.com/mw37lx.jpg look at the last line on the right side of note la"j. also the rambam says in the beginning of the chapter that one who doesnt perform corea3 waheeshta7awoyoh has transgressed. what ashkanazim make minhag form halocho and from halacho to minhag is not my problem. both mori gafe7 and mori arusi agree that teimonim did it. what i am arguing on is why they stopped. i do it at home

Comment: we dont change anything to accommodate peoples needs. as rabbeinu avrohom ban harambam wrights, in hamaspiq la3obdei hashem, that anything which the nabee'eem did, we dont change for anything even if a joy takes it and uses it for avodho zoro.

Comment: ...our socio-halakhic circumstances. This is a major reason for why Mori Arusi seems to be "lenient;" he is dealing with a reality of Temanim being active in the setting of another tradition- such as Ashkenaz - and vice-versa. In such a circumstance, for the sake of striving toward Kelal Yisrael becoming an "Agudah Ahath" (a central requirement for the Ge'ulah), we must find ways to maintain our own traditions while not segregating ourselves from other religious Jews. The fact is that MANY traditions of tafillah existed in the times of the Geonim and no one refused to pray together. Kol tuv.

Comment: Your use of Rabbenu Avraham b. HaRambam does not apply in this case. There he was speaking of being mevatel practices because goyim adopt them. Here, we are talking about multiple customs/valid ways of interpreting/fulfilling the laws of tafillah be-ssibbur coming together in the same place. Many who follow the Rambam (or mainly the Rambam, as I myself strive to do) do not like to hear that Nosah Ashkenaz (sans the late qabbalistic additions) has deep meqori roots in the writings of the Geonim, many in the Siddur of Rasag himself. In my estimation, the Mishneh Torah is the supreme code...

Comment: ...but it is not flawless. And it does not prevent the only valid way of performing many of the misswoth. Even the Rambam would have admitted this, as Rabbenu Avraham his son says often in his writings when expressing a halakhic position contrary to his father, i.e. that had his father heard his reasoning he would have accepted it. Even Mori Yusef writes in an essay quoted by Rav Eliyaqim Ssadhoq shlit"a that he was open to forming a "Nusah Ahidh" (Universal Tradition) upon arriving in EY, he retracted once he found that the effort was only that all non-Ashkenazim assimilate to Nosah Ashkenaz.

Comment: thats the problem. we should indeed separate ourselves from their halochoth and minhagheem. we should set up our own batei deeneem. there is no issur of lo teethjodadhu in such a case. even the beith yoseif says so http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=636&st=&pgnum=70&hilite= look at lamadh bei, i think it is also quoted by mori gafe7 in his intro to one of his saforeem. one cant make aghudo a7ath. that is someone what beith yoseif wanted to do. in joluth we are all sepearte in halocho but one as kalal. other than that we need malach hamoshia7 to fix us.

Comment: problem is htat most teimonim are not learned as they were back then, and therefore they want to feel part of a "bigger picture" and therefore they would rather drop their masoro in order to be part of that bigger picture. also satmar is not helping by making them be mavatel their masoro forcefully. look all over the world. count how many really baladheem/dor dai3eem you have. most became either shami/safaradi mix or ashkenized or "traditional". its time to give up on the "dream" of aghudoth a7ath. and leave the big job for HaShem.

Comment: The Rambam says specifically and emphatically in his Pirush HaMishnayoth that Melekh HaMashiah will NOT be the one to "fix" our situation and neither should we wait for him to do so. Rather, according to Hilkhoth Melakhim 1 & 11, Melekh HaMashiah CANNOT arrive until we re-institute a monarchy through the agency of a REAL Sanhedrin of 71 and a REAL navi approved by them. He write in Hil. Melakhim 11 that the `iqar of belief surrounding mashiah is that the Torah will never change. I am familiar with the Beth Yosef there in that tashuvah, although it does not say what you want it to. It is speak

Comment: sorry to say. that the only way for us to all agree is if all go by RaMbam and drop the zohar and other qabbalistic practices, which for sure wont happen without a war between jews. what do you think the fight was about in regards to rambam and his opposition in his time? they went for "mysticism" and rabbeinu went for science and math. _<Mod note: comment edited for tone.>_

Comment: ing about separate synagogues in the same region or city, some following the Rosh and others following the Rambam. The Beth Yosef rules that those [more prominent] communities who follow the Rosh cannot force the ones follow the Rambam to also go according to the Rosh. NOWHERE in that tashuvah does he discuss them praying together and how to handle such issues if they were both to return to EY from the Galuth. Your assumptions and comments about Temanim are offensive. Temanim are not illiterate sell-outs who will change anything to gain acceptance. Kol tuv.

Comment: What non-Temani "Rambamists" (such as yourself, I assume) cannot admit is that the answer is NOT for everyone to simply drop everything and become Rambamists (thereby solving all of our problems), since even Rambamists cannot agree on their wild and novel interpretations of the Mishneh Torah half of the time! Rather, what the future more likely holds is that halakhic Jews from various mesoroth learn to respect each other, develop ahavath yisrael, and come together to form the Sanhedrin. Then, they will discuss the halakhah - and the majority vote will determine halakhah, not the Mishneh Torah.

Comment: I am a HUGE fan of the Rambam, but he was one Rishon and NO community EVER used the Mishneh Torah as their exclusive and only halakhic text, not even traditional Baladhi Temanim. This is a new - mostly American ba`al teshuvah - development which usually does not fare well. The Rambam wrote his book to teach quickly and easily the halakhah as he understood from his reading of the Gemara, NOT as the final word. In his letters to Yosef Ibn Akhnin he tells him to teach Gemara and the halakhoth of the Rif in his yeshiva. He writes about his son that he wishes him to be a hakham, not a mimic.

Comment: i quoted the beith yoseif on in regards to have 2 separate beith deeneem not for praying together. also in regards to what rabbeinu avrohom ban harambam writes, it is indeed so about praying. his statement was in general for all practices which include praying. http://oi44.tinypic.com/2vs3fah.jpg http://oi43.tinypic.com/2lvjolu.jpg

Comment: T-S AS 182.291 Application to the Muslim court concerning a dispute about Abraham b. Moses Maimonides' attempts to change Jewish prayer customs; Egypt; 1240; Arabic; paper
This draft copy of a question sent by members of the Rabbanite Jewish community in Egypt to the Muslim court is one of many petitions sent by Jews to the Muslim authorities.

Comment: The senders were concerned about the innovations introduced into liturgical Jewish traditions by the group led by Abraham, son of Maimonides. "…A group of Jews whose word is authoritative, namely the leader of the Jews and those of their sages who are his followers, have established the practice of genuflection and prostration in their worship. They have stated this to be an ancient practice and that they have revived an aspect of worship that had fallen into disuse…" The writers hoped that the Muslim religious conservatives, who were in power at the time, would also disapprove.

Comment: also in regards to my statements about teimonim. you have to admit it is true. like i asked you before. how many baladheem do you know who are real baladheem taht go by rambam/their masoroh. most became shami or uneducated and therefore go by ra9abi who claims to be baladhi but goes and prints a shulchon 3oruch for teimonim...

Comment: I think we have reached an impasse. Thank you for the sparring. All the best to you. Kol tuv.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob, Maimonist, could you move this discussion to chat?  If you try to add a comment you should see a "move to chat" link; if you do that all these comments will be imported in a new room.  Comments on posts aren't meant for extended discussions and these may be cleaned up, though a link to a chat room (if present) would stick around.