# any groups that only follow Rambam?

Tags: halacha, rambam

Are there any Jewish groups that consider the works of the Rambam as doctrinally relevant? Meaning they elevate his decisions above those of others, such as those of yosef karo?

Comment: Yes, I knew one in Eretz Yisrael. Also, Yemenites https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_Yemen

Comment: @RabbiKaii interestingly enough, Yemenites follow rambam on everything except his ruling on the type of shofar you need- Rambam says u need a ram’s horn but Yemenites use the horn of a Kudo

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26744/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29680/ . See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53422/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52577/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53459/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the closest you will find in recent history is the Dor Daim sect of the Yemenite community. They were an active community in the early 20th century, but currently don’t seem to have a centralized community. They are strongly anti Kabbalistic (or at least Zoharic and Lurianic kabbala) and strongly adhered to the philosophy of the Rambam to guide their faith. They also followed him in most Halacha areas, as they felt much of contemporary Halacha, including some of the Shulchan Aruch, had been corrupted by Kabbalistic beliefs and customs.
You could read all about them here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dor_Daim

Comment: I knew one in Eretz Yisrael. There are Rambamists, somewhere, he was part of a kehilla. He would enjoy talking to me between netila and hamotzi. They were not Yemenites (but I did see him often at a Yemenite shabbat table). He wore a very thick, big dome-like, dark green knitted kippa

Answer (score 2):

There is a Beit Kenesseth Rambam in Jerusalem that adheres to the Rambam. I believe it was majority Yemenite and it was an eye opening experience the one time I went. The service begins shortly after sunrise. The prayers are only those brought down by the Rambam, with zero modern additions. Everyone did their morning blessings at home so I believe they began with Psalms of Praise (pesukei d'zimra which was only the last 5 Psalms). Then it was Shema. Then Amidah and Torah service. The Torah was read one verse at a time and then repeated in Aramaic targum. Everything leading up to the Torah service was about a half hour to forty five minutes. The Torah reading and Prophets reading was about an hour and a half. A few blessings, one more Amidah and the service was done by about 10:30am. The majority of that time was the reading of the biblical books which made sense. It really restored the idea of what the service is really supposed to be about. The reading of the Torah and our Prophets, without a language barrier.

I don't have their contact information but if you look hard enough I'm sure you'll find them.

*Update*

Commentator asked: "Without a language barrier? Translating the Torah verse by verse to Aramaic is by no means helpful in the modern age"

I agree with you that at this moment, the Aramaic Targum does not help with a language barrier. But it shows that before Halakha got so stratified, we would make choices about our services to get around issues of language barrier. It makes me wonder if we still had a Sanhedrin, would every synagogue read one verse of the Torah, and then read out loud a translation in the local tongue? I'm imagining an Artscroll or JPS Translation for English etc etc.

Commentator asked: "The service is supposed to be about the reading of the Torah and our Prophets without a language barrier? Not praying?"

Almost every other synagogue service I've been to (Ashkenazi, Sepharadi, Moroccan, and Shammi Yemenite Services), the prayers take twice as long as the Torah Reading and reading of the Prophets. To have a Synagogue experience of the inverse, it gives the service an entirely different feel. I wouldn't say the service at the Rambam Synagogue wasn't about praying. But it definitely felt like the Torah and Prophet readings were the number one priority and prayers were a very clear second place priority. And I think that makes more sense for a Shabbat service where historically speaking, this was often the one time people could come and hear those books being read AND translated.

Comment: Without a language barrier? Translating the Torah verse by verse to Aramaic is by no means helpful in the modern age.

Comment: The service is supposed to be about the reading of the Torah and our Prophets without a language barrier? Not praying?

Comment: @DoubleAA You can pray at home on your own, and it is (I suppose) presumed that people at least know enough to say/sound out the prayers on their own. If they can't, praying in the native tongue is acceptable. However, back in the day, you couldn't just buy a Chumash. As such, the primary drive to go to a service at a synagogue would be for the Torah and Prophets, since that is the part that you wouldn't have been able to do alone. Regarding verse-by-verse translation: you are holding the Chumash in your hands while the Torah reading takes place, and this is the modern analogue.

Comment: @Benyamin On the contrary, the institution of Chazarat Hashatz indicates that people came to synagogue to pray [albeit somewhat vicariously] because they couldn't do it themselves at home. That's why hiring a town cantor was so important, even more than having a basic town rabbi, and you could compel everyone to contribute to his salary

Comment: @DoubleAA We can agree that it wasn't a zero sum game. Some people came to pray and the repetition was instituted for that reason. But it's also worth noting in Rambam's time people would get distracted from too much prayer and Rambam wrote a teshuvah recommending the silent amidah be abolished. ""'The abolition of the silent prayer is therefore necessitated by the
particular conditions of the time:" I do not think Rambam would rule thusly with regards to the reading of the Torah/Haftarah

Comment: @Aaron On the other hand the vast majority of communities actually did rule thusly regarding the targum and abolished it. Moreover, classically torah portions were ~1/3 of their current size, while formal paytanic prayer (as would be on Shabbat etc.) was probably longer than our current Amida and said slower and clearer so people could hear and understand and follow.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought the Torah Reading was 1/3 Torah reading in Jerusalem/Israel by custom and "full reading" in Bavel. I would say the classical torah readings were to read the entire Torah during certain Holidays like in Ezras time. And yes most communities did abolish the custom of Targum Aramaic, especially as Aramaic no longer became an understood/spoken language.